# Connecting to cassandra with titan

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, titan

I am new to titan. I want to use titan with cassandra database. But when I start the gremlin server and try to load a graph using command -

```
graph = TitanFactory.open("conf/titan-cassandra.properties")
```

it gives me the following error -

```
Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
```

I dont want to use elastic search. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to connect to an existing graph that was previously configured to use Elasticsearch. By default, the keyspace is named `titan`.

1) You could connect to a different keyspace by updating `conf/titan-cassandra.properties`

```
gremlin.graph=com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory
storage.backend=cassandrathrift
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
storage.cassandra.keyspace=mygraph
```

2) You could drop the existing keyspace. If you used `bin/titan.sh start` from the quick start directions (which starts a single node Cassandra and a single node Elasticsearch),

```
cd $TITAN_HOME
bin/titan.sh stop
rm -rf db/* logs/*
bin/titan.sh start
```

Or if you have a standalone Cassandra installation:

```
cd $CASSANDRA_HOME
bin/cqlsh -e 'drop keyspace if exists titan'
```

Then you would be able to connect with the default `conf/titan-cassandra.properties`.