# Using JanusGraph with Solr

Tags: solr, janusgraph

Setting up JanusGraph i noticed the following in the console:

```
09:04:12,175  INFO ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader:173 - Loaded and initialized config classes: 10 OK out of 12 attempts in PT0.023S
09:04:12,230  INFO Reflections:224 - Reflections took 28 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 2 keys and 2 values 
09:04:12,291  WARN GraphDatabaseConfiguration:1445 - Local setting index.search.index-name=entity (Type: GLOBAL_OFFLINE) is overridden by globally managed value (janusgraph).  Use the ManagementSystem interface instead of the local configuration to control this setting.
09:04:12,294  WARN GraphDatabaseConfiguration:1445 - Local setting index.search.backend=solr (Type: GLOBAL_OFFLINE) is overridden by globally managed value (elasticsearch).  Use the ManagementSystem interface instead of the local configuration to control this setting.
09:04:12,300  INFO CassandraThriftStoreManager:628 - Closed Thrift connection pooler.
```

and then i see the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
```

How do i stop using elasticsearch and switch to Solr?

My properties file is as follows:

```
index.search.backend=solr
index.search.directory=/path/to/directory/for/solr/index/something
index.search.index-name=something
index.search.solr.mode=http
index.search.solr.http-urls=http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr
storage.backend=cassandrathrift

storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
cache.db-cache = true

cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20

cache.db-cache-time = 180000

cache.db-cache-size = 0.25
```

Comment: `Once a GLOBAL_OFFLINE property is set and the janusgraph cluster is initialized, any changes to those properties will never take effect in that cluster, even if the cluster were to be restarted`. So even if you change index backend to solr, it will not take effect, so you have to clear the existing data and restart the janusgraph

Comment: currently there is no data. i see nothing in my solr.... :( which data am i supposed to delete?

Comment: JanusGraph store config in your storage backend in your case cassandra. you need to clear cassandra data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this basically the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187554/connecting-to-cassandra-with-titan/45195599#45195599) for Titan. JanusGraph was forked from Titan.

You are probably trying to connect to an existing graph that was previously configured to use Elasticsearch. By default, the keyspace is named `janusgraph`.

1) You could connect to a different keyspace by updating `conf/janusgraph-cassandra.properties`

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
storage.backend=cassandrathrift
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
storage.cassandra.keyspace=mygraph
```

2) You could drop the existing keyspace. If you used `bin/janusgraph.sh start` from the quick start directions (which starts a single node Cassandra and a single node Elasticsearch),

```
bin/janusgraph.sh clean
```

Or if you have a standalone Cassandra installation:

```
$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/cqlsh -e 'drop keyspace if exists janusgraph'
```

Then you would be able to connect with the default `conf/janusgraph-cassandra.properties`.